# Cannot get past "Installation type" screen after choosing "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7"

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-7

After getting to the screen that states: "This computer currently has Windows 7 on it.  What would you like to do?"  I am not able to continue with the installation process after selecting "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7".

I am running Ubuntu off a USB drive after using UNetBootin and then selecting the "Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" shortcut. Everything included on the online guides worked perfectly up to this point. Very new to Linux, please help?

Answer (score 1):

UNetBootin creates "*bootable* Live USB drives".  I would strongly suggest attempting to boot from the USB drive and installing Ubuntu directly without involving Windows.

Your computer may not be setup to boot from the USB drive. To change this, edit the boot priority options of your BIOS.  Often, you enter your BIOS configuration by pressing F1, F2, F10, ESC or DEL when your computer is booting.

[Enter BIOS](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000192.htm)